# EclipseLink: how to obtain instance of Project class so I can call setDefaultQueryResultsCachePolicy

Tags: java, caching, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

In EclipseLink 2.5.2, how can I obtain the instance of the `org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Project` class that is associated with my existing `PersistenceUnit` / `EntityManagerFactory` so that I can call `setDefaultQueryResultsCachePolicy`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it [from `Session`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28389_01/apirefs.1111/e26376/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/Session.html#getProject__), and you can get `Session` from `EntityManager`.

```
// EntityManagerImpl is from package org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa
Session session = ((EntityManagerImpl) entityManager).getActiveSession();
Project project = session.getProject();
```

Comment: You might want to add a session customizer to your persistence unit properties so that the session is changed only once, upfront, before it is initialized: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Customizers  This allows you to make mapping and other changes to the session and project